# What's "limit doesn't exist" multiplied by limit that equals zero?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

OK, we're having a strong discussion just a day before our Calculus exam. The problem's next: To check if this function is continuous:
$$\frac{y^2\,\sin x}{x^2 + y^2}$$ at (0,0).
We get DNE $\cdot 0$, and can't really understand if it's 0 or something else.

Comment: Please correct my post, it's (y^2) * sinx

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I will, thanks.

Comment: Are you examining the limit at $(0,0)$?

Comment: If you write $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ then the numerator is bounded by $r^3$.

Comment: @Randall yes, edited.

Comment: What, exactly, does "DNE $\cdot0$" mean?

Comment: @Rose asking for the limit is a different question than pondering continuity:  your function does not have $(0,0)$ as part of its domain. So, the limit question is fine, but the continuity question is automatic.

Comment: @BarryCipra DNE as Does Not Exist

Comment: @Rose, what about the "$\cdot0$"? Also, exactly *what* does not exist?

Comment: @BarryCipra if you split the function into two parts, first one everything besides `sinx`, and second part only `sinx`, find limits of those two, and then you get "Does not exist" * 0.

Comment: @Rose, ah, I see what you mean now. You're trying to use $\lim(fg)=(\lim f)(\lim g)$ with $f(x,y)=y^2/(x^2+y^2)$ and $g(x,y)=\sin x$.  But the theorem that establishes the equality $\lim(fg)=(\lim f)(\lim g)$ has assumptions that restrict when you can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need only make the function continuous at $(0,0).$ For that observe that $$\left | \frac {y^2 \sin x} {x^2 + y^2} \right | \leq |\sin x|.$$ So we have $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac {y^2 \sin x} {x^2 + y^2}  = 0$$ by Squeeze theorem. So in order to make the given function $f$ continuous at $(0,0)$ we have to take $f(0,0) = 0.$

Comment: This answer raises a good point.  As OP has written the question, $(0,0)$ isn't even in the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there are two functions $f,g$ such that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to a$, and $g \to \infty$ as $x \to a$. There is no general answer to what the behaviour of $f(x)g(x)$ will be as $x \to a$. It depends on the "rate" at which $f$ and $g$ converge and diverge respectively.

For example, if $f(x) = x, g(x) = 1/x$, then $f.g \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. However, if $f(x) = x^2, g(x) = 1/x$, then $f.g \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Similarly, if $f(x) = x, g(x) = 1/x^2$, then $f.g \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$.

So, there is no general answer to this question.

Now, coming to your specific question, let $(x,y) = (r.\cos a,r.\sin a)$. Hence, $$\frac{y^2\sin x}{x^2 + y^2} = \frac{r^2\sin a\sin(r\cos a)}{r^2} = \sin(a) \sin(r\cos a)$$

So, here, as $(x,y)$ approaches $0$, $\sin(a) cos(r\cos a) \to 0$ because $r \to 0 \implies \sin(r \cos a) \to 0$. Hence, the function is continuous at $0$ because the limit is $0$ regardless of how $(x,y)$ approach 0$.

For more interesting behaviour, I suggest you examine the slightly modified function: $$f(x,y) = \frac{y^2 \cos(x)}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that

$$\lim f(x,y)$$ does not exist,

$$\lim g(x,y)=1$$ and $$\lim h(x,y)=0.$$

Then neither

$$\lim\frac{f(x,y)}{h(x,y)}$$

nor

$$\lim\frac{g(x,y)}{h(x,y)}$$ do exist, but

$$\lim\left(\frac{f(x,y)}{h(x,y)}\right)h(x,y)$$ does not exist while

$$\lim\left(\frac{f(x,y)}{h(x,y)}\right)h(x,y)=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

When looking at limits at the origin for multivariate functions (especially ones that have $x^2+y^2$ in them), it can help to go to polar coordinates: $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$. You then take the limit as $r\rightarrow 0$. If this limit exists and is independent of $\theta$, then that is the value of the limit at the origin. Otherwise, the limit doesn't exist. For this function,
$$
\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta \sin(r\cos\theta)}{r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta} = \lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\left[\sin^2\theta\sin(r\cos\theta)\right] = 0
$$
This is independent of $\theta$, so the limit at the origin is $0$.

Comment: That's the first thing I did, but our Calculus professor doesn't consider polar coordinates to give an "accurate answer" of limit existence.

Comment: @Rose That's strange, as they most certainly do. Perhaps he's referring to the fact that the $r$ limit has to not only exist, but also be independent of $\theta$, which many students forget.

Comment: Well I'm aware that it mustn't depend on an angle of approach, but that's what we've been told.